# APC is quick - then bogs down server

Tags: nginx, memcached, apc, php

I am tentatively serving up a crap site with a good amount of traffic until new development is finished.

The server is a 4GB cloud server with 2 CPU cores running NGINX, PHP-FPM, APC, Memcached and a cloud database server (Rackspace).

The site, to let you know how bad it is, gave me an uncached load of 1.2 with JUST be roaming around on it quickly. Terrible. 170 queries per page, some with 2000 records or more. Terrible.

So, being on Joomla, I enabled APC. QUICKLY snapped up the site to more than livable while we develop.

Now the site is live and consistently has 30 - 60 live visitors according to GA.

Here's the weird part. Regardless if I use APC or Memcached, as the site runs quickly at first after resetting php-fpm.. and then it goes for a while and gradually loads up and the CPU is at 1.x, 2.x and upward gradually. Never coming back down even after visits subdue a bit.

Why is this happening? I've scoured the internet looking for any consistent direction for php-fpm settings, APC settings, etc.. It's so mis-mosh out there so Im hoping for some sound advice on calculating and determining what settings need to be as the demand changes.

Below are my settings - at this point the only thing I can think of would be to CRON "service php-fpm restart" every 30 minutes or so.

```
[APC]
apc.stat = 1
apc.max_file_size = 2M
apc.localcache = 1
apc.localcache.size = 128M
apc.shm_segments = 1

apc.ttl = 3600
apc.user_ttl = 600
apc.gc_ttl = 3600

apc.cache_by_default = 1
apc.filters = 
apc.write_lock = 1
apc.num_files_hint = 7000
apc.user_entries_hint = 5000
apc.shm_size = 64M
apc.mmap_file_mask = /tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.include_once_override = 0
apc.file_update_protection = 2
apc.canonicalize = 1
apc.report_autofilter = 0
apc.stat_ctime = 0

apc.stat = 0
```

(this also ends up fragmenting pretty hard - I have apc.php available if anyone needs more information)

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 80
pm.start_servers = 32
pm.min_spare_servers = 16
pm.max_spare_servers = 56
pm.max_requests = 1000
```

(I've played with these.. never seems to make much difference but I don't think I've found any sound advice either)

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated :-/

Comment: About 7K hits a day - joomla site - after APC enabled it's 5M-ish per page load - before APC being enabled it was closer to 15M-ish per page load.

Comment: I'm curious what type of FPM PM you are using? IE: static, dynamic, ondemand. I'm also curious if you've tried changing these values and playing with each of their settings to see if this makes any difference.

Comment: As far as I know (lol) my settings above should make it dynamic. I've not tried static but I have played with these a tich. The problem is - I don't understand what ranges are even appropriate. Reasearch has led me to such a wide range - who says they're doing it right with a higher load site?

Comment: If it helps - When I blitz the site - It ALWAYS errors for like 5-10 seconds 20% through the blitz and then comes back at like 20-40% and works fine. So there's a bottleneck. Haven't been able to pinpoint why though.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if you changed the settings since you posted. I'm also curious if you've checked the APC admin page that comes with PHP and see if perhaps there is a clue there? It comes with the PECL APC package and it's called apc.php

Comment: Ya I've been watching it and trying to research / learn. It's been active for a while now and only 4.5% fragmentation - usually settles around 9.7%

Here are some screens:

http://d.pr/i/5bYm - APC
http://d.pr/i/Ppm7 - (Mothership - on serverdensity)
http://d.pr/i/Pxw0 - Top @ 71 active users (81%!!? Also there are usually 5 - 10 other php-fpm tasks running at lesser CPU usage)

I was trying to use memcached but it did the same thing if not worse when set to 2000MB - 3500MB cache (4GB total server)